# Table Column on hover not working due to background-color

Tags: html, css

I got this CSS code that highlights column and row on hover. It's perfectly working. However, I have a background-color as part of the UI design on the DIV. I can't get rid of it and this is showing on top of the absolute position with negative z-index and thus the hover effect stops showing up. How do I keep the background-color and still make it work?

```css
.size {
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 50px 0;
}

table {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}

td,
th {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

th {
    background-color: #fff;
}

td:hover::before {
    background-color: #eee;
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    left: -5000px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 10000px;
    z-index: -2;
}

td:hover::after {
    background-color: #ffa;
    content: '';
    height: 10000px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -5000px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="size">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-11 text-center">
                <h2>Size</h2>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="head"></th>
                                <th>xxs</th>
                                <th>xs</th>
                                <th>s</th>
                                <th>m</th>
                                <th>l</th>
                                <th>xl</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>neck</th>
                                <td>14</td>
                                <td>14.5</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                                <td>15.5</td>
                                <td>16</td>
                                <td>16.5</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>chest</th>
                                <td>18</td>
                                <td>19</td>
                                <td>20</td>
                                <td>21</td>
                                <td>22</td>
                                <td>23</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>length</th>
                                <td>26.5</td>
                                <td>27</td>
                                <td>27.5</td>
                                <td>28</td>
                                <td>28.5</td>
                                <td>29</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>waist</th>
                                <td>17.5</td>
                                <td>18.5</td>
                                <td>19.5</td>
                                <td>20.5</td>
                                <td>21.5</td>
                                <td>22.5</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>sleeve</th>
                                <td>32.75</td>
                                <td>33</td>
                                <td>33.25</td>
                                <td>33.5</td>
                                <td>33.75</td>
                                <td>34</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried editing the z-index to 5 for `td:hover::before` and to 10 for `td:hover::after`?

Comment: That would cover the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of a hacky workaround -

```
.size {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
  padding: 50px 0;
}
```

rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06); and  #eeeeee are the same shade of grey, but the first is actually a mostly transparent black. This will allow you to continue to see the hover effects behind the background without trouble shooting the z-index issue. A better solution would be to solve the z-index problem instead, though, but just incase you can't.

Answer (score 1):

```
rgb = '#eee';
a = '0.5';
rgba='('+parseInt(rgb.substring(1,3),16)+','+parseInt(rgb.substring(3,5),16)+','+parseInt(RGB.substring(5,7),16)+','+a+')';
```